# C# MVC5 JsonResult

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jsonresult

I am trying to check for whether or not a CustomUrl is taken within my application.  The problem is that when I click the submit button, nothing happens.  I having a very difficult time understanding what I have done wrong.

To clarify: There is no javascript errors, the page does not get submitted.  There are no errors anywhere of any sort for me to go on.  Also, if I remove **[Remote]** section from AccountViewModel, so it does not attempt to make the check, the page will submit and it will also record the value in the database.  So I'm fairly certain it has something to do with the validation I tried to put in place.

Here is the code:

MembersController.cs

```
public JsonResult IsCustomUrlInUse(string customUrl)
{
    return Json(!UserManager.Users.Any(x => x.CustomUrl == customUrl), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

AccountViewModel.cs

```
[Required]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
[Display(Name = "Custom URL")]
[Remote("IsCustomUrlInUse", "Members", ErrorMessage="Custom Url is already in use.  Please choose another.")]
public string CustomUrl { get; set; }
```

Register.cshtml

```
@model Azularis.System.Events.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script> 

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Members", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomUrl, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomUrl, new { @class = "form-control"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

EDIT:

Answering questions in comments:

1. Network Tab in Developer options is capturing the entry of Custom URL field.
2. When I remove Remote, the validation for minimum characters kicks in and displays an error.  Also, even while Remote is there, the minimum character limit still kicks in.

Example of the network tab: http://postimg.org/image/8e2e1hesx/

I have also removed the bundle in the view, to make sure this is not happening due to duplication, but still the same thing happens.

EDIT 2:
I added a Logging line in the IsCustomUrlInUse method, but it never gets triggered.  Can it be that somehow I need to enable json call to the server?  As in the MVC is blocking json calls until I enable it in settings somewhere?

EDIT 3:

I managed to produce this error, I'm not sure how as I am not able to replicate it, but maybe this helps:

```
2015-11-29 13:50:19.4659||System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/__browserLink/requestData/c244808430ad49a5afee6a0ecb685cf7' was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
2015-11-29 13:50:47.0584||System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/__browserLink/requestData/c244808430ad49a5afee6a0ecb685cf7' was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Can you check that fiddler or browser network tab captures trace for IsCustomUrlInUse action. Also, you have added jqueryval twice in your view --- one through direct js reference and second through bundle. Adding jquery validation file twice creates irrelevant behavior.

Comment: Also, can you confirm that if you remove Remote attribute then validation error appears for required and string length data annontations.

Comment: @user1672994 I have edited my question to answer your questions.

Comment: @user1672994 I also added a picture of the network tab.  The last line in that picture is continuously growing.  I'm not too familiar with what all this means.

Comment: Can you change the line `@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })` to `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` to see if it logs any validation error on click of submit.

Comment: Also add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomUrl)` in your view. It will display the validation message if there are any for CustomUrl input.

Comment: @user1672994 yeah I tried adding validationMessageFor and it only complains if its under 3 characters.  I tried just now implementing both of your requests and the results are the same.  I don't get any error messages of any kind.  Network tab is still recording as before.  I also checked web.config and I have **ClientValidationEnabled** and **UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled** set to true.  So that is not either.

I also managed to get an error message earlier, I added it to my question.